# Is the set nowhere dense or connected or compact?[NBHM- PhD Screening test, topology-2013]

Tags: general-topology

> $S$ ={$A$ is in $M_n$($\mathbb R$): tr($A$)=0}. Then which of the following
>   statements are true.
>
> 1. $S$ is nowhere dense in $M_n$($\mathbb R$).
> 2. $S$ is connected in $M_n$($\mathbb R$).
> 3. $S$ is compact in $M_n$($\mathbb R$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the trace as a linear map $Tr:M_n(\mathbb R) \to \mathbb R$; the linearity of $Tr$ is easy to verify: $Tr(\alpha A) = \alpha Tr(A)$ and $Tr(A + B) = Tr(A) + Tr(B)$ both follow from the definition of $Tr(A) = \sum_1^n A_{ii}$, where $A = [A_{ij}]$.  It is clearly non-trivial since $Tr(I) = n$.  As a linear map between finite dimensional real vector spaces, it is clearly continuous.  Thus $\ker (Tr)$ is an $n^2 - 1$ dimensional subspace of $M_n(\mathbb R)$.  This shows it is nowhere dense and that it is connected.  As a linear subspace, it is clearly not bounded, hence cannot be compact.

Hope this helps.  Happy New Year,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: THANK YOU. $HAPPY NEW YEAR$

Comment: You are most welcome!  And thanks for the "acceptance"!  Happy New Year!

Comment: @RobertLewis : I really like what you said "As a linear subspace, it is clearly not bounded, hence cannot be compact" :) :) But i do not understand other justifications for being connected and nowhere dense :O could you please explain a bit more...

Comment: @Praphulla Koushik: Thanks for the kind words.  A set is nowhere dense if its "closure has empty interior" (a direct quote from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_dense_set).  The subspace $\ker(Tr)$ is closed.  But if $p \in \ker(Tr)$, any open ball containing $p$ cannot lie within $\ker(Tr)$, hence $(\ker(Tr))^\circ = \varnothing$.  Furthermore, any subspace $S$ is path connected, $t\vec v + (1 - t)\vec w \in S$ for $\vec v, \vec w \in S$, hence connected.  Hope this helps.  Cheers!

Comment: But you have said nothing like that in your answer :O Just now i could understand why dimension of space of trace $0$ matrices is $n^2-1$ because of Trace map... I guess any subspace of dimension less than $n$ is nowhere dense in space of dimension $n$ so, space of trace $0$ matrices having dimension $n^2-1$ is nowhere dense in space of matrices $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ of dimension $n^2$.. Am i correct?

Comment: Oh yes... every path connected space is connected... any subspace is path connected so is connected... I like this also :) :)

Comment: @Praphulla Koushik:  no I didn't say it, I guess I assumed that stuff was general knowledge . . . and yuppers, you figured it out!  +1 for the comment. And thanks again! Best!

Comment: sorry to bother you so much but i need one more help... I am interested in seeing  whether certain subset of matrices is connected/compact/nowhere dense.. Can you suggest if there are any other ways to see this... Anyhow i got two tools... any subspace having dimension less that that of whole space is nowhere dense and any subspace is connected... I would like to learn something similar to this and possibly more general i mean when the given set is just a subset but not a subspace... could you please suggest something..

Comment: @Praphulla Koushik:  it's hard to say in general without knowing what the subset is, how it is defined, etc.  But if it is a *submanifold*, for example, you have some tools . . . how is your subset defined?  Maybe you should ask it as a question, to avoid a long comment stream?

Comment: yes yes... i would try on my own and would ask if i have some doubt.. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @Praphulla Koushik:  well, once again, no problem.  And best of success in your further work on this!